# Java Reflection on Interfaces

Tags: java, generics, methods, reflection, interface

mainly my question is about how I could create a "dynamic" method which I could Override for different objects.

So having this interface

```
public interface GenericInterface{

    public List<Object> getAll() throws Exception;

    public Object addObject(Object object) throws Exception; // This should use reflection

}
```

And now extending GenericInterface in this other Interface

```
public interface CarInterface extends GenericInterface{

     @Override
     List<Object> getAll() throws Exception;

     @Override
     public Object addObject(Object object) throws Exception;


     public Object newSpecificMethod() throws Exception;

}
```

And now having a public class

```
pulic Car implements CarInterface{
     //...

     @Override
     public Object addObject(Object object) throws 

          //.. here some logic

          return object;
     }

     //...
}
```

So how could I "Override" the method's name?

Instead of having

> Car.addObject(object);

I would like to have

> Car.addCar((Car) object);

I know that is related with Reflection but I don't know how I could do it. Any suggestion?

Comment: It seems to me that the sub interface doesn't have to override the two methods, they are the same.

Comment: @grape_mao You're man man, after a while I just realized that only helps me to write the code faster for all my entities but it's pointless to have this GenericInterface

Comment: Well it depends, we could keep a generic interface. JEY's answer is correct, there's just no need to re-declare the two methods.

Answer (score 2):

use generic:

```
public interface GenericInterface<T>{

    public List<T> getAll() throws Exception;

    public T addObject(T object) throws Exception;
}

public interface CarInterface extends GenericInterface<T>{
    public Object newSpecificMethod() throws Exception;
}
```

Comment: Regarding the method's name, it cannot be changed via override. Instead, OP may wish to change the `addObject` name to the more general `add`.

Comment: With a strongly typed method it's pointless if the method do exactly the same

Comment: I got at the conclussion that it's better to use a global name as @Vulcan menthioned before. So at the end I used  `addItem(T item)` instead of  `addObject(T object)` which is not so "friendly".